# One to many relationship MySQL, Order By three or more tables

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, one-to-many

I have a master table with several support tables that have a one to many relationship

```
Master
Master_ID, Date, Name, Details
1, 02/10/2011, Bob Smith, example text
Changes
Change_ID, Master_ID, Date, Original, New
1, 1, 05/10/2011, test, test2
2, 1, 06/10/2011, chagge, change
Comments
Comment_ID, Master_ID, Date, Text
1, 1, 05/10/2011, test comment
2, 1, 05/10/2011, more comment
3, 1, 06/10/2011, another
```

I want to join all three tables, and then use PHP to format everything into an array

```
SELECT `Master`.*,`Changes`.*,`Comments`.* 
FROM Master 
JOIN `Changes` USING(Master_ID), 
JOIN `Comments` USING(Master_ID) 
WHERE `Master`.Master_ID = 1 
ORDER BY `Master`.Master_ID,`Changes`.Change_ID,`Comments`.Comment_ID
```

When I do this it sorts by the Master ID and then the Change ID and then the Comment ID.  However the problem is, that I want it to sort in relation to the Master ID, while the Comment ID gets sorted in relation to the Change ID.  I've tried a few different ways of sorting, but I can't get it to do what I want, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I've added sample output, if you'll notice the Change_ID column is not in ascending order, because it's sorted in relation to Change_ID not Master_ID

```
Master_ID   Date    Name    Details Change_ID   Master_ID   Date    Original    New Comment_ID  Master_ID   Date    Act of Violence
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    148 118 12/10/2011 10:42    red reder   309 118 19/09/2011 13:13    test!
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    148 118 12/10/2011 10:42    red reder   310 118 19/09/2011 13:14    In Vehicle
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    148 118 12/10/2011 10:42    red reder   311 118 19/09/2011 13:14    act of 
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    148 118 12/10/2011 10:42    red reder   339 118 22/09/2011 13:02    blah blah
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    148 118 12/10/2011 10:42    red reder   483 118 12/10/2011 9:24 
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    148 118 12/10/2011 10:42    red reder   506 118 12/10/2011 10:42    
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    149 118 12/10/2011 10:42    done    none    309 118 19/09/2011 13:13    test!
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    149 118 12/10/2011 10:42    done    none    310 118 19/09/2011 13:14    In Vehicle
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    149 118 12/10/2011 10:42    done    none    311 118 19/09/2011 13:14    act of 
118 19/09/2011 13:13    Bob Smith   example text    149 118 12/10/2011 10:42    done    none    339 118 22/09/2011 13:02    blah blah
```

I've written this function to sort the results into an array, the sample function only works with two tables, with the second table with a one to many relationship.  However, I have a more complicated version that works with more than two tables, but the problem is with the sorting.

**mysqlResult** is an associative array from a mysql_query call, **parent_key** is the name of the primary key of the parent table, **child_key** is the name of the primary key of the child table, **child_table** is the name of the child table, **child_fields** is an associative array of the names of all the fields in the child table

function cleanJoin($mysqlResult, $parent_key, $child_key, $child_table, $child_fields)
    {
    $last_parent = 0;
    $last_child = 0;
    $ch_ctr = 0;

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mysqlResult); $i++)
{
    if ($mysqlResult[$i][$child_key] != $last_child)
    {
        echo "new child!";
        $pr_ctr = count($answer[$i]);
        foreach ($child_fields as $field => $type)
        {
           $answer[$pr_ctr][$child_table][$ch_ctr][$field] = $mysqlResult[$i][$field];
           unset($mysqlResult[$field]);
        }
        $ch_ctr++;
    }
    if ($mysqlResult[$i][$parent_key] != $last_parent)
    {
        foreach($mysqlResult[$i] as $field => $value)
        {
            $answer[$i][$field] = $value;
        }
    }
    $last_parent = $mysqlResult[$i][$parent_key];
    $last_child = $mysqlResult[$i][$child_key];
}

return $answer;
```

}

Comment: You'll have to give an example of A: the output it gives now that you don't like and B: the output that you want. I have no idea how to answer this.

Comment: I've added sample output, what I'm trying to demonstrate is how the third primary key (Comment_ID) is not in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but maybe the WITH ROLLUP modifier for the GROUP BY clause is the answer you are looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html.

In your query you should change

```
ORDER BY `Master`.Master_ID,`Changes`.Change_ID,`Comments`.Comment_ID
```

into

```
GROUP BY `Master`.Master_ID,`Changes`.Change_ID,`Comments`.Comment_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

I am not sure if it will work with JOINS, as the examples in the documenation all use a single table, but there's no harm in checking in out.